# Will issues arise packaging libc and pthread with your C apps?

Tags: c++, c, libraries, dynamic-linking

The issue I hit, is that I am packaging shared libraries with my code in order to load GNUTLS, except for libc, because I figured any system will have it. Most of them don't have the required 2.14 for it(except for Ubuntu or others with daunting upgrades and repo butchering). I know it's bad form to be dependent like that, but I need a very recent build of GNUTLS, so it was the only solution I thought of.

In order to solve the libc issue, is it safe to package libc & pthread(another dependent), with my program? My program is Java, using JNI to load these libraries if that's relevant. This is also all for Linux.

Comment: Are you curious about just the technical aspects of safety or also licensing concerns? From a technical perspective what you're doing is very similar in certain ways to compiling and distributing your own toolchain. It can be done but requires careful cross-compiling and you may need to package more than you bargained for to get the whole dependency chains correct.

Comment: It's only 8 libraries combined. As for licencing, its all GNU linux stuff, and my stuff is GNU(and I don't modify theirs), so licencing *should* be fine. I'm more concerned about the technical aspect. @JTrana

Answer (score 3):

`libc` is so central to Linux systems (see also [nnsswitch.conf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html)) that I would avoid shipping my own one. Most systems have [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (latest version is 2.22 since august 2015; my stable Debian/Jessie has a 2.19 GNU libc; another computer running Linux/Mint has a 2.17 GNU libc). So I feel that a 2.14 GNU libc (published in 2011) is quite ancient these days. Some Linux distributions might use other C standard libraries like [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)

Did you consider instead having some installation procedure (perhaps just `make install`) which check first that the `libc` is recent enough, and otherwise fail with a meaningful error message?

The current version of [GNUTLS](http://www.gnutls.org/) is 3.3.17 (since august 2015). You could ship it if so needed.

Pthreads are part of GNU libc (even if sometimes GNU libc also install a separate `libpthread.so` library) since [NPTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library).

BTW if you are developing free software, you might publish it as source code, package it for a one or two distributions, and put the burden of packaging it for other distributions on them.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem is to use a make and automake system like GNU Autotools to configure your code for the function calls in libc you need rather than the libc directly. That will solve the portability problem.

https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/

It is highly unwanted to transport your own libc as it might cause problems and unspecified behaviour.

Comment: How does this satisfy portability? If the OP needs a specific minimum version of libc to be on the machine the program runs on, not the one it is compiled and linked on.

Comment: The original poster was breaking the ultimate design of unix by porting libs not intended for other systems. He said deployed to many versions "most of them".  That's looking at the problem backwards. If you write portability in you don't break unix sys v.

Comment: Make install is in auto tools as a recipe of automake so basically I suggested the up voted answer and one ill informed comment makes it less valid. Lol